# Figure forces everything away from page

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a problem with a figure because LaTeX insists on putting on its own page no matter the size I give it.

The code gives me a page with the section header and hello, then a new page with the figure, and again a new page with hello. I would like to move the figure up beneath the section header.

```
\clearpage

\section{Time Series' of Explanatory Variable Averages}
hello


\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!tbph]
\centering
    \caption{Time Series of Average Independent Variables}
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\linewidth,scale=0.3}
\begin{flushleft}
\footnotesize
The figure reports graphs the time series development of each independent variable used in the default prediction number over the full sample period from 1995 to 2015. All variables are equally weighted.
\end{flushleft}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_prof}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill  
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_lev}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_cash}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_mb}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_exret}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_rsize}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_sigma}
    \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{full_dtd}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

hello
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The behavior you're experiencing is exactly what the `sidewaysfigure` is designed to do. If you don't want this behavior, don't use this environment. Instead, you may want to look into the properties of the `rotate` environment, provided by the `graphicx` package.